# Nest server not connecting to MongoDB cloud UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: URI malformed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

My NestJS backend needs to connect to the mongodb cloud, I followed the docs from [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb)

The following error threw up in the terminal:

```
    (node:6920) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: URI malformed
    at new ConnectionString (D:\growth\quizbackend\quizbackend\node_modules\mongodb-connection-string-url\src\index.ts:113:13)
    at Object.parseOptions (D:\growth\quizbackend\quizbackend\node_modules\mongodb\src\connection_string.ts:249:15)
    at new MongoClient (D:\growth\quizbackend\quizbackend\node_modules\mongodb\src\mongo_client.ts:332:22)
    at D:\growth\quizbackend\quizbackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:785:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (D:\growth\quizbackend\quizbackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:782:19)
    at Mongoose.createConnection (D:\growth\quizbackend\quizbackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.<anonymous> (D:\growth\quizbackend\quizbackend\node_modules\@nestjs\mongoose\dist\mongoose-core.module.js:60:63)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at D:\growth\quizbackend\quizbackend\node_modules\@nestjs\mongoose\dist\mongoose-core.module.js:20:71
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:6920) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:6920) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, 
promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My app module code:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
import {MongooseModule} from '@nestjs/mongoose'
@Module({
  imports: [UsersModule,MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb+srv://icfoajscijwq90j@cluster0.8rxa2.mongodb.net/nest-js-db?retryWrites=true&w=majority')],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I doubled check my username and password but they are correct, is there any need for encoding them or why the error is throwing up any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you to remove the connection string from the question. Anyone can connect to your database with it. You should change your creds.

Comment: @NenadMilosavljevic Thank you for your concern, Yes I will change the creds once the issue is resolved

Comment: @SamiurKhan Did you tried to change your password to something without special characters?

Comment: @LarsFlieger The issue was resolved once I changed the password without any special characters

Comment: @SamiurKhan Great. I found the part in their documentation. There you can see which characters are allowed and how to deal with illegal ones. I added it as an answer for everyone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that your **username** and **password** in the URI Connection string **doesn't have any illegal characters**.

> If the username or password includes the following characters:
>
> ```
> : / ? # [ ] @
> ```
>
> those characters must be converted using percent encoding.

Based on their documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: thanks the issue is resolved, how do I close the question

Comment: You're welcome. You do not have to do anything nor close the question. If you marked an answer it's "closed"