# Digital Ocean droplet Mongodb connection string says malformed Uri

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, digital-ocean

I have a digital ocean droplet where I am running a react frontend and a node server as the backend that I have named "backend." I am using mongoose and have mongodb version 7.0.2 and mongoose version 2.0.2. I turned on authentication on the database and it works as expected (running show dbs without being logged in is refused, then logging in it does show the databases). When checking status it says the mongodb is running.

I have a full admin user AdminMark and mark. In the mongo shell I ran use markDatabase01 and then created a user "accountUser" and was able to add data to the database so it is created and listed.

I have tried many different connection strings and they all fail. Below are three different strings I tried. I have tried these strings with all three users as well and none work. I have also tried using localhost in place of 127.0.0.1 and that didn't work either. My environmental variables work correctly, and the error message console logs the connection string. (I hid the password though from this post.) Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@127.0.0.1:${process.env.MONGO_PORT}/markdatabase01`)
.then(() => console.log("Database 1 connection successful."))
.catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    console.log(`mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:<hidden>@127.0.0.1:${process.env.MONGO_PORT}/markdatabase01`);
    console.log("Database 1 connection failed.");
    mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@0.0.0.0:${process.env.MONGO_PORT}/markdatabase01`)
        .then(() => console.log("Database 2 connection successful."))
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            console.log(`mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:<hidden>@0.0.0.0:${process.env.MONGO_PORT}/markdatabase01`);
            console.log("Database 2 connection failed.");
            mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@127.0.0.1:${process.env.MONGO_PORT}/markdatabase01?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+2.0.2`)
                .then(() => console.log("Database 3 connection successful."))
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.error(err);
                    console.log(`mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:<hidden>@127.0.0.1:${process.env.MONGO_PORT}/markdatabase01?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+2.0.2`);
                    console.log("Databse 3 connection failed.");
                });
        });
});
```

> 0|backend  | Server started on port 1337
> 0|backend  | mongodb://accountUser:@127.0.0.1:27017/markdatabase01
> 0|backend  | Database 1 connection failed.
> 0|backend  | mongodb://accountUser:@0.0.0.0:27017/markdatabase01
> 0|backend  | Database 2 connection failed.
> 0|backend  | mongodb://accountUser:@127.0.0.1:27017/markdatabase01?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+2.0.2
>
> 0|backend  | Database 3 connection failed.
>
> /root/.pm2/logs/backend-error.log last 15 lines:
> 0|backend  |     at new MongoClient (/root/markdrecoll.com/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:48:63)
> 0|backend  |     at _createMongoClient (/root/markdrecoll.com/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:886:14)
> 0|backend  |     at NativeConnection.openUri (/root/markdrecoll.com/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:741:29)
> 0|backend  |     at Mongoose.connect (/root/markdrecoll.com/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:404:15)
> 0|backend  |     at /root/markdrecoll.com/server/index.js:37:18
> 0|backend  |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> 0|backend  | MongoParseError: URI malformed
> 0|backend  |     at new ConnectionString (/root/markdrecoll.com/server/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/lib/index.js:102:23)
> 0|backend  |     at parseOptions (/root/markdrecoll.com/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/connection_string.js:191:17)
> 0|backend  |     at new MongoClient (/root/markdrecoll.com/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:48:63)
> 0|backend  |     at _createMongoClient (/root/markdrecoll.com/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:886:14)
> 0|backend  |     at NativeConnection.openUri (/root/markdrecoll.com/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:741:29)
> 0|backend  |     at Mongoose.connect (/root/markdrecoll.com/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:404:15)
> 0|backend  |     at /root/markdrecoll.com/server/index.js:43:26
> 0|backend  |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is not a valid IP address to connect to

Comment: That is only one of many different connection strings I tried and didn't work. I saw the 0.0.0.0 suggested on some stack overflows saying that it passes in all IPs. 

More importantly the 127.0.0.1 and localhost don't work. Any suggestions for those?

Comment: The "Malformed URI" error is a client-side error from the driver.  For testing, try removing `${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@` from the connection URI.  If the error changes to "not authorized" or "authentication failed", that would indicate that something in the username or password is breaking the URL parsing.

Comment: Good idea thanks. So I removed the credentials and it actually said the database connection was successful. When trying to make calls though I get "Command insert requires authentication."

Any idea why I am able to connect when I thought I shouldn't be able to without credentials? And what would I do to fix this?

Comment: MongoDB handles authentication after the tcp connection has been established, so you are permitted to connect, but when authorization is enabled, the only thing you can do is authenticate.

Comment: Hmm I thought usually the username:password@ is how connection strings authenticate? Either way do you know (or could point me toward documentation) for how to authenticate after the connection is established?

Comment: That is true, if you pass username/password in the URI the driver will automagically handle the authentication after connecting.  To make this all work, try URL-encoding the username and password before concatenating them into the connection string.

Comment: Your mention of encoding made me come across the mongodb note that if the password includes certain characters it must be encoded. I had autogenerated a secure password that had symbols in it. That turned out to be it! Sorry that was a simple thing I should have realized. I have been struggling with this for a couple days and it just turned out the password I had made was breaking the connection sting. 

Thanks again and if you post it as a solution I will mark it as solved to give you the credit.

Comment: That already exists over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68972951/2282634